# Android spinner onItemSelected can't take string array position

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, spinner

I have a spinner and some text views that changes on different spinner item selected.
I have an external text file to store data that looks like:

```
Mission Impossible: Fallout| 6.6| 148| Tom Cruis, Henry Carvill| 11:00 am, 1:10 pm, 2:55 pm, 3:05 pm, 5:10 pm| mifallout.jpg
The Predator| 5.8| 118| Olivia Munn, Boyd Holbrook| 1:10 pm, 2:50 pm, 4:55 pm, 6:55 pm| predator.jpg
```

I read and store them into array and setting them to a spinner adapter. But now the on ItemSelected doesnt change the text views accordingly **UNLESS** i hard-code them like

```
 if (spinnerValue.equals("Incredibles 2")) {
                ratingText.setText("8.0");
                durationText.setText("125");
                castText.setText("Craig Nelson, Holly Nelson");
```

Hard-coding them isn't a good practice and i want to do it dynamically.Below is my attempt:

Reading and storing them into array, then add to array list so that it can be attached to adapter for spinner.

```
 try{
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("movie_superhero.txt")));
            while ((sMovies = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                if (!sMovies.equals("")) {
                    arrMovies = sMovies.split("\\|");
                    list.add(arrMovies[0].toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

onItemSelected:

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            ratingText.setText(arrMovies[1].toString());
            durationText.setText(arrMovies[2].toString());
            castText.setText(arrMovies[3].toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

All of the variables are accessible anywhere in class, but why cant I get the correct correspond value based on the selected item in spinner?

Comment: show your layout `support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` code please

Comment: just use a modal type array list instead of using a string array and string list. No need to complicate things this much

Comment: The `support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is just a built-in layout for spinner. It can either be that or `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`